# "Multiplication" Problems

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

This was originally going to be featured in a puzzle compilation I'm planning, but it was swapped out for a different idea I had. The answer is an English word. Are you able to solve the equations below?

**True Equations:**
2x2 = 1
1x1 + 3x5 = 6
1x7 = 8
1x4 + 6x2 = 9

**Unsolved Equations:**
1x1 + 5x3 = ?
1x5 + 1x7 = ?
1x3 + 5x3 = ?
2x5 = ?
2x4 + 1x7 = ?
1x1 + 3x2 + 6x2 = ?

Hints:

> 1x7=8 is important. How can you make an 8 using only 7?

> The numbers do not mathematically change the output. They are a way of containing information, or rather, instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> FRAUDS

The equations refer to

> Seven segment displays

Specifically,

> Each product has a first and second half. There is a standardized way of numbering a seven segment display, shown below (with letters instead of numbers)
>  [image]

> The first half refers to a starting point, and the second half refers to a length. For example, 2x5 fills in segments 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. If there are multiple products in an equation, then both sets of segments are simultaneously filled in. When we do this to the six equations at the bottom, we get the letters F, R, A, U, D, and S, leading to the final answer of FRAUDS.

> Note: the second equation is wrong, but if you switch around the numbers in each product then it makes an R, so it just seems to be a mistake.

Comment: Correct!
I thought this would be really obscure to most people, but knew that someone would eventually figure it out. Took less than 24 hours too.